# Cannot mock Action Context with Mockito/PowerMockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, struts2, mockito, powermock

I have been using Mockito for unit testing the action classes in my code. I have been successful in performing end to end test for almost every action but one. This particular action depends on ActionContext for retrieving the session and I must remind you that it will not be possible to replace the existing code with the implementation of SessionAware and setSessionAttributes().

Basically, the error I get is a null pointer exception on Action Context and even after tremendous investigation, the exception remains as it is.

The particular code which causes this error is :

```
book = (Book) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("sessionKey");
```

and the error log I get is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.syb.ao.test.ApplyPromoDetailsTest.prepareTests(ApplyPromoDetailsTest.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
```

I have tried just about everything I could to get this running but just cannot find a solution.

Comment: *it will not be possible to replace the existing code with the implementation of SessionAware* - Why? You need to setup action context.

Comment: I am sorry..but by 'implementing session aware' i meant not using setSessionAttributes to set the map in session.

Comment: I know that action context could be mocked up, but I don't understand why not to create a new action context and use it in your test, initialize it with the mocked session?

Comment: Hi Roman, I think you have a good solution. Could you please elaborate? Or maybe give me some sample code? It would be very kind of you.

Comment: *Why* can't you implement `SessionAware`? This is one of the reasons I almost always advocate against using the action context, and why in the Struts 2 FAQS it specifically states that implementing `SessionAware` is preferred (http://struts.apache.org/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html).

Comment: Changing it now would affect countless classes as well as functionality.